# Is there a limit to the number of Ajax requests that can be launched on Apache

Tags: ajax, apache2, prototypejs

Is there a limit to the number of simultaneous Ajax requests than can be launched toward an Apache server? For example, consider the following function to update div elements on a page (prototype JS):

```
function trigger_content_update(cell) {
    //asynchronous : false is required for this to work properly
    $$('.update').each(function(update_item){  
        new Ajax.Request('/neighbouring?.state=update_template&dummy='+(new Date()).getTime(),{
            asynchronous: false,
            parameters: {divid: update_item.id, source: cell},
            onComplete: function(response) {
                var elm = response.getHeader('Element');
                if ($(elm) !== null) { $(elm).update(response.responseText) }
            }
        });
});

}
```

On my HTML page, there are 8 div elements that are marked with the "update" CSS selector, thus launching 8 ajax requests. The code works fine with the asynchronous property set to false, but as soon as i set asynchronous:true i can observe (in Firebug) most Ajax requests returning a 500 status (internal server error).

Once this occurs, it is required to restart apache to recover.

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with the AJAX end. You will find a detailed error message in the Apache server logs. If you post that, people might be able to tell what goes wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd check the server side code that's handling the requests.

As far as Apache is concerned, your Ajax request is just a POST - the same as if you'd submitted a form. 8 simultaneous requests should easily be handled by Apache, so it suggests that the server side code that Apache is running is locking up - perhaps it's trying to write to a data file and finding it locked?

Comment: Thanks, i'll inspect my server side code with a magnifying glass and report back.

Comment: It turns out that my DB handle class was incapable of handling all the incoming simultaneous requests

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a test case where I sent out 10,000 simultanuous Ajax calls to a service. Works fine on Apache Tomcat. All service came back with a proper answer.

It sounds like your service is having some internal synchronization issues.